# ANDROID: Adding items from an arraylist to an AlertDialog

Tags: android

I am trying to add the contents of my array list to an AlertDialog, but it comes up with error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
```

Here is my code snippet that I am having problems with:

```
 public void ShowOnlineUserDialog(){
     CharSequence[] users = {_onlineUsers.get(1), _onlineUsers.get(2),    _onlineUsers.get(3), _onlineUsers.get(4)};
     AlertDialog.Builder onlineUser = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     onlineUser.setTitle("Online Users");
     onlineUser.setItems(users, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            System.out.println("User clicked!");

        }
    });
     onlineUser.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();

        }
    });
     onlineUser.show();
 }
```

Moreover, is there a more efficient way of adding to the alertbox, for loop maybe? I'm sorry but my lack of knowledge in arrays fails me.

Any help would be amazing! Thank you!

EDIT: If I set my code out this way:

```
 String user1 = _onlineUsers.get(1);
     String user2 = _onlineUsers.get(0);

     CharSequence[] users = {user1, user2};
```

It works perfectly, but I would like to find a more efficient way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

Take `String[] users` instead of the `CharSequence[] users`

and do like below:

```
users = new String[_onlineUsers.size()];
System.out.println("Total Item is: "+_onlineUsers.size());
users = _onlineUsers.toArray(users);
System.out.println("USERS :"+_onlineUsers.toArray(users));
```

That will convert your whole `ArrayList<String> _onlineUsers` to `String[] users`.

Hope it will help you.

Be Free to ask any question if it is not solve your issue.

Comment: Works great thank you!

Except now every time I click the button (It's attached to a buttonclick) it adds the users again and again. Is there a way to reset the value every time?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct and has no bug. I think you have to check it -

```
CharSequence[] users = {_onlineUsers.get(1), _onlineUsers.get(2),    _onlineUsers.get(3), _onlineUsers.get(4)};
```

Check that it is able to fetch string from it or not.